# wildcard target in makefile doesn't work

Tags: gcc, makefile, g++, wildcard

I have this simple rule in my `Makefile`:

```
PP=g++ -std=c++0x
%.o: $.cpp
        $(PP) $< -c -o $@
```

When I run `make parse_utils.o`, the command be executed should be:

```
g++ -std=c++0x parse_utils.cpp -c -o parse_utils.o
```

But in fact it's:

```
>make parse_utils.o
g++    -c -o parse_utils.o parse_utils.cpp
```

And I got a compile error because I used `C++11` syntax.

Is this wildcard rule wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target is wrong. Change

```
%.o: $.cpp
```

to

```
%.o: %.cpp
```